# Facing Issue for data migration from ElasticSearch 8.3 to Opensearch 1.3

Tags: elasticsearch, data-migration, amazon-opensearch

I am trying to migrate database & data from ElasticSeach 8.3 (instance) to Opensearch 1.3 (domain). For that using _reindex API for data migration. It is giving below error : -

Error  : -

- Error parsing the response, remote is likely not an OpenSearch
  instance
- [search_response] failed to parse field [hits]
- [hits] failed to parse field [hits] illegal_argument_exception
- "status" : 500

Note :- same _reindex API is working fine when i have tried to migrate data from ElasticSeach 7.17 to Opensearch 1.3.

But facing error when using _reindex API for data migration from ElasticSeach 8.3 to Opensearch 1.3.

Please let me know if any clue about this error, how to resolve this. or any other alternate way to migrate data.

Thanks

Comment: base on what document you are trying to reindex from opensearch to elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

why do you need to reindex data when you want to migrate the indexes frpm one cluster to another?

if you run it on AWS you can take a snapshot to an s3 then register the same bucket as a snapshot repo on target cluster and restore the snapshot there:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-take-snapshot.html
https://opensearch.org/docs/1.2/opensearch/snapshot-restore/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/managedomains-snapshots.html